# Group months by year, days by month/year

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a database like so:

```
date
11-23-2013
11-24-2013
...
01-05-2014
```

I am trying to create hashes that are sorted by year and then by month, without repeating the values (say, there are 30 instances of November, it should show up only once and skip to the next month). I am trying to get them to show up in the JSON as:

```
{2014[05,04,03,02,01], 2013[12,11]}
{12[31,30,29...], 11[30,29,28...]}
```

I am new to Rails and so far this is what I have:

controller

```
 @year = Model.select("year(date) as date").group("year(date)").order("date DESC")
 @month = Model.select("month(date) as date").order("date DESC").group_by{ |m| m.date.year }
 @day = Model.select("day(date) as date").group("day(date)").group_by{ |d| d.date.month }

 respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => :show }
      format.js
      format.json { render :json => {:year => @year, :month => @month, :day => @day}}
```

Month, for example, what is showing up in the JSON as:

```
31557600.0: [{date:1, id:null}]
63115200.0: [{date:2, id:null}]
94672800.0: [{date:3, id:null}]
126230400.0: [{date:4, id:null}]
347133600.0: [{date:11, id:null}]
378691200.0: [{date:12, id:null}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `group_by` method should do this for you.

```
all_dates = Model.order("date DESC").map(&:date)
@months_in_year = all_dates.group_by{|x|x.year}
@months_in_year.each_value {|months| months.map!{|m|m.month}.uniq!}
@days_in_month = all_dates.group_by{|x|x.month}
@days_in_month.each_value {|days| days.map!{|d|d.day}.uniq!}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, good point... the first line should have been creating an array of dates, not an array of records. Now fixed.